# Calculating mean of multiple stochastic processes and setting a lower threshold

Tags: programming, simulation, finance

Thanks to “Rod Lm” I got some very nice input for the following problem.

My intention is to simulate within a `Manipulate` function a given number of possible stock price paths and to calculate their mean. So, if something is manipulated the “new mean” is also calculated automatically and both are shown by a line and numerically within the chart. I would also like to know how I can also calculate the mean outside the chart. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Mean[Table[
   RandomFunction[
     GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0.1, 0.2, 100], {0, 250, 0.05}][
    "Path"], {20}][[All, -1]]]
```

The next step -if possible- is to introduce a lower boundary. So for example if the initial stock price is 100 then the boundary could be at, let’s say, 70. First, I want the boundary to be shown by a line. Second, I would like to stop all stochastic processes that fall below this threshold and then receiving the mean from all remaining processes.

Alternatively, if it’s not possible to stop the processes that fall below the threshold, I also just want the mean of the remaining processes that are beyond the threshold. 
Third, I also would like to have a manipulable threshold. So, in short, I want to be able to switch the threshold between 20 and 90 and then receive the mean of the processes that remain beyond this boundary.

Is something like that possible? If yes, I would be really thankful if I would receive some suggestions how to solve my problem, or at least parts of it.
So far I have done the following and is it even possible to modify this code in such a manner that my problem can be solved?

My code so far:

```
 Manipulate[
   SeedRandom[seed]; 
   ListLogPlot[
    Table[RandomFunction[
     GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[μ,σ,S0], {0, 250, 0.05}]["Path"], {P}], 
    Joined -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Time", "St"}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Forecasted Stock Price\n (Brownian Motion)", Bold], 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thin, Lighter@Gray}]
  ], 
  {{S0, 100, "Initial Stock Value"}, 100, 500, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{μ, 0.01, "Drift μ"}, 0.01, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{σ, 0.01, "Standard Deviation σ"}, 0.01, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{P, 1, "Paths"}, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{seed, 77777, "New Random Case"}, 10000, 999999, 1}, 
 Button["Set Initial Values", {S0 = 25, μ = 0.01, σ = 0.01}, ImageSize -> 150], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Variable name `S_0` doesn't look correct to me. You can't use an underscore (= `Blank`) in a variable name.

Comment: Changed it...now better?

Comment: What are the problems you are running into? The more specific your question the more likely it is someone will help...

Comment: the Problems I am running into are that I simply want to calculate the mean of a specific number of paths at the end of the period and also introduce a visimble threshold let's say at 70 which can also be manipulated. and if possible I would like to calculate the mean of those paths which remain beyond this threshold. do you understand my problem? if no, please let me know so that I can be more precise. Thank you

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do, but what are the problems you have with the implementation?

Comment: @sebhofer thanks. My problem is that I am actually still unexperienced with Mathematica and I do not know how to assemply my Intention. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could start by selecting the parts below the threshold with `Position` and replace them by the relevant means. That may not be the fastest method but a straightforward one.

Comment: @sebhofer thank you, but how can I in the first place introduce a threshold which can be manipulated within my above given function?

Comment: @MilanIvica Are you trying to show anything related to options strike prices? I mean, if prices fall below strike prices you don't "continue" simulating the stock price anymore?

Comment: @ Rod Lm I am trying to do something similar. So the stochastic processes should simulate the asset value of a corporation, whereas the threshold constitutes it’s debt value. So for now I just want to show all this in a chart. So far I am calculating the mean of all processes, however, in the next step I would try to figure out how just to calculate the mean of the processes which remained beyond the threshold. In other words I want to modify my code in such a manner that it just calculates the meant value of the asset paths which remain beyond the debt level.  Do you know what I mena?

Comment: @MilanIvica The way you're calculating the mean of paths is incorrect... you're basically simulating random paths and, then, you're calculating the mean of **another set** of random paths...

Comment: @ Rod Lm is this also true for the code which can be found here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26383/introduction-of-straight-line-into-manipulate-function

Comment: @MilanIvica Another thought: you're simulating stock prices, instead of total value of assets... so in this case you're also calculating the debt *per share* of the company, right? The threshold is not the total value of debt, but the debt per share, right?

Comment: @MilanIvica Yes, this is also true for the code you've linked above... the mean is not correctly computed...

Comment: @Rod Lm Thank you that you found the mistake, any ideas how I can calculate the mean properly?...And yes, I am simulating the total asset value and not the stock price. The methodology should be the same. So one possible stochastic process constitutes the asset value whereas the threshold constitutes the total debt value which is constant.

Comment: @MilanIvica Another thought: it is not "recommended" to use mean of processes which are not stationary... so be careful when using GBM's with drift...

Comment: @MilanIvica Keep in mind that prices (and also the mean of prices!!!) increase as a function of time, i.e., they are not stationary ...

Comment: @Rod Lm I thought about it, but was not sure. Do you have an idea how i could i.e. just calculate the mean of all processes at the end of the final period. in other words and time point T and disply it somewhere in the chart?

Comment: @MilanIvica please try my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correctly compute the mean, try this:

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[seed];
meanvector := Mean[assets];
assets = Table[RandomFunction[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[μ, σ, S0], {0, time, 0.1}]["Path"], {P}];
G1 := ListLogPlot[assets, GridLines -> {{}, {watermark}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "St"}, PlotLabel -> Style["Forecasted Stock Price\n (Brownian Motion)", Bold], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thin, Lighter@Gray}]];
G2 := ListLogPlot[Mean[assets], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Darker@Red}]];
Show[G1, G2],
{{S0, 25, "Initial Stock Value"}, 1, 500, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{μ, 0.08, "Drift μ"}, 0.01, 0.2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{σ, 0.2, "Standard Deviation σ"}, 0.01, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{P, 6, "Paths"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{time, 10, "Time t"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{watermark, 25, "Watermark"}, 1, 500, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{seed, 1, "New Random Case"}, 1, 100, 1},Button["Set Initial Values", {S0 = 25, μ = 0.08, σ = 0.20, P = 6, time = 10, watermark = S0}, ImageSize -> 150],
ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot for your help. now it works perfectly! :)

Comment: @Ron Lm thak you a lot, I just slightly changed your code by making the time manipulable. However, I also wanted to introduce a line, which should symbolise a kind of threshold. I tried to do it, but I had some Problems. If you have time, could you please take a brief look at it?. I think the Problem is somewhere in G3

Comment: @MilanIvica I edited your suggestion for some syntax error and misusing on functions (your original definition of `G3`). I also formatted the code for more readability. Please see the edit history for detail and let me know if I did something wrong.

Comment: @Silvia and @MilanIvica You don't need to define `debtlevel = Line[{{0, t}, {T, t}}]` or `threshold = Line[{{0, t}, {T, t}}]`. You only have to add `GridLines -> {{}, {watermark}}` to the `ListLogPlot[]` function...

Comment: I only did a a minimal modification for correcting the error in @Milanlvica's edit suggestion on this answer. Its YOUR answer, so please feel free to edit it.:) But I personally think it would be better if you indent your code more for its readability. btw +1

Comment: @Silvia Thank you! I personally prefer to use, for instance, `\[Mu]` instead of $\mu$ when pasting a code... anyway thank you again!

Comment: It's a habit differing from body to body. And yes `μ` may not be rendered correctly in browsers that don't support Unicode..